# How can I SELECT data which one field are member of an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, field

Use PHP and MySQL. I have an array, P, which contains the value of possible category number of products. In my table it also have the field "category" which stored category number and the others. What I want is to SELECT data in all rows which field "category" have any value in array P.What should I do?

For example
P=[1,7,13]

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category=P[1] OR categry=P[2] OR category=P[3]....
```

Comment: Is `P` a column name? If so, do you realize that arrays are not a data type in `MySQL`. What do you actually have stored in that column? A number? A string?

Comment: @MicaelRushton P is not a column name. I stored number in field "category".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [implode() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category IN (".implode(",", $P).")"
```

Comment: Thanks X.L.Ant , Your answer is very compact that suitable to use in my code.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$categories = implode(', ', $p); // Where $p is the array 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category IN ($categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `IN` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE category IN (p[1], p[2], p[3])
```

with `implode`:

```
$categories = implode(',', $P);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation:

```
$P = array(1, 7, 13);
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category=".$P[1]." OR 
            category=".$P[2]." OR category=".P[3]."....";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category={$P[1]} OR 
            category={$P[2]} OR category={P[3]}....";
```